# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 Schedule Alerts Issue

Tags: alert, url, notifications

I hope you guys could help me out. So the issue is that after creating a scheduled alert daily summary... the links returned notified were wrong. Here are scenario of what happened.

-I had the user delete the old alerts and recreate it. Set the notification immediately on the library and it worked wonderfully.
-This time I had the user recreate an alert, but only this time it was set to Send a daily summary at 3pm. Then when the schedule hits at 3pm... the links were wrong.

The original URL was http://yoursite/sites/IT. But once the summary came.. clicked on the links for the daily summary and the user gets page cannot be displayed. The URL appears to end up being "http://sites/sites/IT/" when it supposed to be "http://yoursite/sites/IT".

What could be wrong? Oh and every zone is by default. No AAM setup or anything.

Sincerely,
Matt L.

Comment: The URL you are seeing in the alerts also part of AAM? Or configured anywhere? Is correct URL is FQDN? What about the wrong URL?

Comment: We didn't setup anything in the AAM. Everything is out of the box setup so our http://yoursite/sites/IT should be in Default zone.

Comment: Our http://yoursite/sites/IT should be FQDN because it goes with no problem. This URL is only accessible within our domain and its not extended outside our domain. The issue happens when we create a scheduled summary daily lets say at 3pm for anything that's changed in a library... the report that we get has all the item urls redirecting to http://sites/sites/IT. However, normal notification alerts that we create that sends immediately has no problems, because the links point to the correct URL which is http://yoursite/sites/IT

Comment: So I am wondering why that is..

Comment: From where sites URL are coming? Is it valid URL? If only yoursites in the AAM then from where sites URL coming?

Comment: That is the part I am wondering, which is weird. The "http://yoursite/sites/IT" is the valid URL so it should be coming from "http://yoursite/sites/IT" upon creating the scheduled daily summary reports. But instead, the links the daily report sends back to us is showing "http://sites/sites/IT". So when clicked on the links... it opens up IE's page cannot be displayed. In IE's URL field shows that its "http://sites/sites/IT" instead of "http://yoursite/sites/IT" that's why the page cannot be displayed. Just to let you know that if we create a normal immediate notification, it works fine.

Comment: Is sites / address being used in your farm? Is it a server name or dns ?

Comment: Hi Waqas, I did more research and found a fix for it. It was a KB patch and a Hotfix CU Update fixed it. It was KB2751999 and the KB2768000. KB2768000 must be installed first before going into KB2751999. Also must stop the service in order, sptimer, search, search host controller. After the update, start the service in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it via KB2751999 and KB2768000. Before installation, must stop the services first in order: sptimer, search, then search host controller. Make sure that they are in "manual" and not automatic service, because the patches and hotfix will ask you to reboot the server. Right after installation, start the services in reverse order.